# "Которых" или "которого" для множественного числа

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, согласование, падежи, множественное-число

Как правильно:

1. 21 вопрос, для котор**ых** заканчивается конкурс
2. 21 вопрос, для котор**ого** заканчивается конкурс?

Речь о вопросах, для которых участники жертвуют часть своей репутации, например, [таких](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured).

Comment: Вы не могли бы  объяснить контекст? Что это за вопросы такие, "для которых "заканчивается конкурс"?

Comment: 21 вопрос с заканчивающимся конкурсом

Comment: @vp_arth как вариант перевода вполне может сгодиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как вариант перевода вполне может сгодиться

Перевод? Вы не об этом часом?
http://conversationstartersworld.com/21-questions-game/

Тогда откуда у вас слово "для"?

***21 вопрос, завершающие конкурс.***

Почему во множественном? Я так чувствую, наверняка сказать трудно. Но есть косвенное подтверждение.  Понятно, что отслыка к согласованию сказуемого тут именно что ни при чем. Однако в упомянутом §184 есть пункт

> 8. Если при счетном обороте имеются слова все, эти или другие в роли определения, то сказуемое ставится во множественном числе,
>      например: Недавно построены и эти семь домов; Все двадцать одна
>      страница переписаны заново; На столе лежат приготовленные к отправке
>      пять пакетов.

Отсюда недвусмысленно следует, что **определение**  при количественно-именном сочетании подобного типа стоит во множественном числе. Правда, тут надо заметить, что определение *целый, все* и некоторые другие вообще часто выделяют в отдельную группу по согласования по грамматическим категориям, так что уверенности нет.

> Речь о вопросах, для которых участники жертвуют часть своей репутации,

Тогда понятно. Вот опять этот кривой перевод слова bounty... Да, здесь токае возможно:

***21 вопрос, для которых заканчивается конкурс.***

Хотя я бы подумал и над

***21 вопрос, конкурс которых заканчивается***

В конце концов, почему конкурс именно **для** вопросов? В отношении грамматического числа - всё сказанное в силе, согласование - множественное.

Comment: Уточнил в вопросе о каком конкурсе речь.

Comment: @alexolut Ох, простите великодушно, об этом не подумал. Добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Выбираем вариант: 21 вопрос, **для которых** заканчивается конкурс.

Розенталь §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте) [XLIII. СОГЛАСОВАНИЕ СКАЗУЕМОГО С ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

**Правило:** При составных числительных, оканчивающихся на один, сказуемое, как правило, ставится в форме **единственного числа**, например: Двадцать один делегат прибыл на совещание;  **Форма множественного числа данной конструкции может быть обусловлена контекстом,** например: Двадцать один делегат встретились за круглым столом (сказуемое-глагол встретились указывает на взаимное действие, которое выражается формой множественного числа). Двадцать один ящик с посудой, **которые** были доставлены на базу, попали туда по ошибке (влияние придаточного предложения с союзным словом которые в форме множественного числа);

Так как допускаются обе формы, то выбираем **семантический**  (а не формальный) принцип согласования во множественном числе. Такое согласование кажется более уместным в сложном предложении, когда придаточная часть имеет определенную самостоятельность.

Comment: Вы не могли бы пояснить, откуда следует, что "Так как допускаются обе формы".

Comment: Прямо из приведенного текста и следует. Рассматриваются варианты, когда удобно применить ед. число, а когда  - мн. число.

Comment: Вот только при чём тут сказуемое?

Comment: Сказуемое  тут ни при чем, я просто цитирую существующее правило. Из этого правила делаю выводы: (1) форма мн. числа не запрещена;  (2) на выбор влияют частные факторы.  После этого  для заданного предложения определяю свои факторы. Также стоит помнить о том, что  семантическое решение в современном языке применяется чаще, чем раньше. Это означает, что при сомнениях лучше выбрать мн. число, реально соответствующее  количеству предметов.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы шла речь о сказуемом, оно бы было во множественном числе :

*6) при составных числительных, оканчивающихся на один: Двадцать один человек подтвердил это. Форма множественного числа сказуемого употребляется, если в предложении есть придаточная часть с союзным словом **который** во множественном числе: Двадцать один ящик с посудой, которые были доставлены на базу, попали туда по ошибке.*

Но в данном предложении нет сказуемого, вернее, Вы нам его не написали. Предложение - то всё-таки нужно писать полностью. Смысла предложенной фразы я, например, не поняла.Конкурс состоит обычно не из вопросов, а из заданий, а из вопросов состоит викторина. Если речь идёт всё же о том, что конкурс кончается, когда закончились эти вопросы, то, может быть, так:

...21 вопрос в заключение (в конце) конкурса.

С придаточным предложением фраза будет в любом случае неказистой:

...21 вопрос,из которых был составлен конкурс,...

...21 вопрос,которыми оканчивался конкурс,...

...21 вопрос, которыми конкурс был исчерпан,...

... 21 вопрос, составляющий(заключающий)конкурс,...

Comment: Уточнил в вопросе о каком конкурсе речь.

Comment: Понятно. В таком случае - "для которых"